# How to correctly catch and process RQ timeouts in Python?

Tags: python, redis, queue, task-queue, python-rq

Trying to find a good way to catch a timeout of an [RQ](http://python-rq.org) job, so it can be requeued after the timeout.

Basically, the correct solution would provide a way (for example, an exception handler in the worker or something of the sort) to requeue the job that timed out.  Also, if the job goes back to the `failed` queue, that's a good answer too.

Thanks very much!  Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use [exception handling](http://python-rq.org/docs/exceptions/). From the docs:

> Jobs can fail due to exceptions occurring. When your RQ workers run in
>   the background, how do you get notified of these exceptions?
>
> Default: the failed queue The default safety net for RQ is the failed
>   queue. Every job that fails execution is stored in here, along with
>   its exception information (type, value, traceback). While this makes
>   sure no failing jobs "get lost", this is of no use to get notified
>   pro-actively about job failure.
>
> Custom exception handlers Starting from version 0.3.1, RQ supports
>   registering custom exception handlers. This makes it possible to
>   replace the default behaviour (sending the job to the failed queue)
>   altogether, or to take additional steps when an exception occurs.

You could also store jobs in a redis sorted set with job_id as key and `time.time() + timeout` as score, and then have a worker run `ZRANGEBYSCORE sorted_set 0 [current_time]` and process whatever's returned as a timed-out job.

Comment: Thanks!  This is correct.  For future reference, the job raises a `JobTimeoutException` which can be handled by the worker exception handler, however you choose to define it.